# How to pause the execution of a @test until the execution of @BeforeSuit?

Tags: java, batch-file, automation

I am writing a TestNG program where I want to perform some operation before my test gets executed. Basically I want to execute a `.bat` file before the test starts. Inside the .bat file, I am doing some Installation and Uninstallation of a software. Here is my code inside `@BeforeSuit`

```
@BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        try {           
            String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\Users\\adutta\\Desktop\\uninstal-install.bat"};
            Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);  
            p.waitFor();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am having 2 problems.

1. I want to pause the execution of my program until the batch file in not get executed completely.
2. When the batch file is getting executed, it's not getting executed in an expected manner. The batch file will first check whether the software is installed or not, if it is installed then it will be uninstalled first then again it will install. But if the software is already installed then it's running the installation code first and then it's running the uninstallation code, as a result, the software is uninstalled at the end of the execution. And yes, as uninstall takes some time, the rest java code is not waiting for the same, it's simultaneously getting executed, which is undesired. I want to pause the execution when the batch file is executing. Which is nothing but the 1st problem.

Here is my batch file content -

```
@echo off

if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Host Analytics\SpotlightXL" (
GOTO UNINSTALL
) else (
GOTO INSTALL
)

:UNINSTALL
    CALL C:\Users\adutta\Desktop\uninstall.bat
    GOTO INSTALL

:INSTALL
    CALL C:\Users\adutta\Desktop\install.bat
    exit
```

How can I solve these problems? Any solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your batch file from what I can tell. TestNG by design will wait for a configuration method to run to completion before it proceeds with executing other configuration methods or test methods for that matter. TestNG doesn't attempt any parallelism there.

You would need to ensure that your batch file has appropriate wait/sleep mechanisms that would ensure that it returns only after all the activities scripted in the batch file run to completion.

Within your `@BeforeSuite` method, you would need to add appropriate polling logic that would wait for the activities to be completed and then proceed.

Currently from your code it looks like `p.waitFor();` is returning back immediately which explains why your `@BeforeSuite` method exits before your software installation/uninstallation activities are complete.

Comment: See, I want to stop the execution of `@Test` until the `@BeforeSuite` is getting executed. As there is a batch file executing, I think it is considered as a different thread. And that's why the `@Test` is getting executed though the `@BeforeSuite` is not yet completed.

Comment: How to stop the execution of `@Test` until the execution of `@BeforeSuite`.

Comment: `@Test` will not proceed until `@BeforeSuite` is not completed

Comment: No, when I am executing a Batch file which is basically uninstalling software, the `@BeforeSuite` is completing before the execution of that batch file. The uninstalling is going on simultaneously, and the command prompt is remaining open.  I want the `@BeforeSuite` to complete its execution after the completion of the batch file.

Comment: That is what I been saying. You would need to add wait instructions in your batch file that ensures that the batch doesn't terminate until the uninstall is complete. Have you tried putting in anything around that ?

Comment: Hey, can you please post a sample code for the same? I have tried p.waitfor(). But it's not working. I am sorry. Please send a sample code which will wait for the completion of the batch file execution and then start the `@Test`.

Comment: `p.waitFor` is not the place. How do you ascertain that the installation is complete? You need to alter your batch file to include a polling logic. That is something only you can do because I don't have visibility to it.